# Binary Calculations on a Bounded Generic Type

Tags: java, generics, recursion

I want to create a function to calculate the power of a number of the type Number  ([the class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html)) via recursion. There is an issue in the following line:

```
return base * NumberOpp.power(base, pow - 1);
```

It doesn't know how to perform the '*' operation. I am guessing this is because of the generic type. It is bounded which I think would fix the problem. I tried casting (it's a little ugly.) It didn't seem to work either.

```
return (T) (Number.doubleValue(base) * Number.doubleValue(NumberOpp.power(base, pow - 1)));
```

All the code is below:

```
public class NumberOpp {
    public static <T extends Number> T power(T base, int pow){
        if (pow == 1) { /* If power is one return base */
            return base;
        }else{ /* Else recursivly multiply by base until power is one */
            return base * NumberOpp.power(base, pow - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use the [implementation Java already provides](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double))?

Comment: The `*` multiply operator only works on numeric *primitives*. By definition, Java generic types cannot be primitives, so there is absolutely no way for return type `T` to be compatible with the `*` multiply operator, not even with auto-boxing, because that is something the compiler does, and it doesn't know which type `T` might be, so it doesn't know which unboxing operation to apply (int? long? double? ...).

Comment: Short answer: it is an assignment to learn better how to use recursion. Yet, I might want to operate on generics in the future.

Comment: Is this impossible?

Comment: Yes, it's impossible to use `*` multiply operator with generics.

Comment: To be able to use the `*` operator Java would need to support operator overloading which it does not so your best option is to either convert you type to a primitive numeric type or provide your own multiplication function that takes two of your `Number` types. Considering your type the former is likely to be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only perform numeric operations (such as multiplication) on numeric primitive types. `Number` has no automatic conversion to a primitive numeric type, which is why your `<T extends Number>` type bound doesn't help.

You can decide to perform the operation of a specific numeric type, such as `double`:

```
public class NumberOpp {
    public static <T extends Number> double power(T base, int pow) {
        if (pow == 1) {
            return base.doubleValue ();
        } else {
            return base.doubleValue () * NumberOpp.power(base, pow - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

This will accept any numeric type as input, but will always return a `double` result.